# Blue Card for Czech Republic with no university Degree

Tags: blue-card, czech-republic

I am being transferred from my company in South Africa to Prague and want to apply for a Blue Card instead of employment card. I dont have a university qualification but have 10 years working experience in a skilled field. 
Will I have any problems in having my blue card approved?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Czech ministry of foreign affairs](https://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/eu-blue-cards.aspx):

> Duly completed university education or higher vocational education, the duration of which was at least 3 years, is deemed to be a high level of skills.

You are therefore not eligible for a blue card.